# Using Power Automate to connect my Excel inputs to Azure ML Studio API endpoint and do predictions

Tags: excel, azure, machine-learning, power-automate

I am figuring out how I can use Power Automate to configure a flow which can connect my Excel file inputs with my Azure ML Studio API endpoint. Ideally this flow will be triggered when one of my column values in Excel is added or modified.

[image: Excel inputs]

Based on the iris dataset I have created a simple Machine Learning model with an API endpoint in Azure ML Studio. The model needs 4 inputs and based on these inputs it returns a predicted label.

[image: Input data to test endpoint]

I have created an Excel file which has 4 columns (sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width), each containing a value as can be seen in the Excel inputs screenshot.

In Power Automate I was able to connect to my Excel file using the 'List rows present in the table' action. In this action I can find my table as 'Table1'.

Which next steps  should I take in Power Automate to connect to the API and be able to receive a prediction in return?

This is how my flow currently looks.

[image: Current flow]

So I am having some difficulties with transforming the input data in such a format that it can be provided as input to the API. In the following screenshot is displayed how I connect to my API using a Bearer token and the specific URI.

[image: API connection]